# Why does Clojure/REPL treat a a float and integral representation of same number different?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, I wrote a simple function kept debugging only to realize in the end that.

```
(= 3 3)
```

is `true`

BUT

```
(= 3.0 3)
```

is `false`

Why?

I know that there are problems with floating point arithmetic where one should not directly compare two floating point values.

Even in Java, 3.0 and 3 will be equal and probably lot of other languages.

Comment: FYI https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/AqA6z6jKwuQ/6yl5KO_yGuoJ

Comment: Thanks. Can you please put that as an answer ?

Comment: Stackoverflow etiquete prohibits links-as-answers (e.g. they tend to expire). It would be awesome if *somebody* could write excerpt of that talk as an answer.

Comment: That 'somebody' turns out to be Dominic Kexel :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not if the same type.

Note how java's `equal` also retuns false:

```
> (.equals 3.0 3)
false
```

or consider the following java programm:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
   Integer i = 1000;
   System.out.println(i.equals(1000.0));
   System.out.println(i==1000.0);
 }
```

**Output:**

> false
>   true

---

There's a difference between the [`=`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/=) and the [`==`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/==) function

> =
>
> Equality. Returns true if x equals y, false if not. Same as
>   Java x.equals(y)...

so if you want to compare the values of the nums, use `==`

> ==
>
> Returns non-nil if nums all have the equivalent
>   value (type-independent), otherwise false